# Whole phrase search possible in solr for double quotes

Tags: solr

I want to do a phrase search in solr without analyzers being applied to it 
eg - If I search for **"DelhiDareDevil"** (i.e - with inverted commas)it should search the exact text and not apply any analyzers or tokenizers on this field
However if i search for **DelhiDareDevil** it should use tokenizers and analyzers and split it to something like this **delhi dare devil**

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there an option wherein if I have a query in double quotes it simply ignores all the tokenizers and analyzers and applies it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of any Out of the Box approach, you can copy field the content to a new field with no analysis.
And, You can define your own query parser and have the query being searched on the field with no analysis.